# How can post parameters month and day in calendar date select tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, calendar

I installed calendar_date_select gem and I'm trying to post format params in calendar_date_select tag with only month and day.

Calendar Date select script works perfect but when I select a date it shows this format "Year-Month-day" so what I want is do click this will show only the month and day inside calendar_date_select_tag is that possible? or maybe another way to remove the year in log like this?

Here is the log:

```
Processing TestController#sending (for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-22 17:17:06) [POST]
Parameters: {"d1"=>"01-01", "d2"=>"31-01", "authenticity_token"=>"yeah=", "commit"=>"Search"}
```

I don't want to remove the year each time to make this working because actually is working fine when remove the year and keep the month and day.

Here is the controller

```
def sending
  @clients= Client.find_by_mysql(["select * from clients where date_format(happy_birthday,'%m-%d') BETWEEN ? AND ?",params[:d1],params[:d2] ])
end
```

Here is the view

```
<head>
 <% CalendarDateSelect.format=(:hyphen_ampm )%>
 <% calendar_date_select_style "silver" %>
 <% translation_calendar %> 
</head>

<% form_tag :controller=>"test",:action=>"sending" do %>
  From: <%= calendar_date_select_tag "d1",params[:d1] %>
  TO:   <%= calendar_date_select_tag "d2",params[:d2] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :class=>"button" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the screenshot

[image]

I tried this but I got undefined method `strftime' for "01-01":String

```
<%= calendar_date_select_tag "d1",params[:d1].strftime("%m-%d")%>
```

Please somebody can help me or maybe advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your question and that's so easy, try this:

In your controller:

```
def sending
 ##### THIS IS IF YOU HAVE PROBLEMS WITH NIL PARAMS IN CALENDAR TAG
 if params[:d1].nil?
   @d1 = params[:d1]
 else
   if params[:d1].present?
     @d1 = Date.parse(params[:d1]).strftime("%m-%d")
   end
 end

 if params[:d2].nil?
   @d2 = params[:d2]
 else
   if params[:d2].present?
     @d2 = Date.parse(params[:d2]).strftime("%m-%d")
   end
 end
 ################

 @clients= Client.find(:all,:conditions=>['date_format(happy_birthday,"%m-%d") BETWEEN ? AND ?',@d1,@d2]  )
end
```

In your view:

```
<% form_tag :controller=>"test",:action=>"sending" do %>
 From: <%= calendar_date_select_tag "d1",@d1 %>
 TO:   <%= calendar_date_select_tag "d2",@d2 %>
 <%= submit_tag "Search", :class=>"button" %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this tips can help.